# Map data type creation

Tags: scala

What does this expression do?

```
val m = Map(1 -> 2, 2 -> 4)
```

This is the return value:

```
scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int, Int] = Map(1 -> 2, 2 -> 4)
```

Comment: You're creating a normal Scala `Map` with two entries. The first entry is mapping 1 to 2, and the second entry is mapping 2 to 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What does this expression do?

Note: this is not an expression, it is a [*value definition*](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/04-basic-declarations-and-definitions.html#value-declarations-and-definitions). A `val` definition does not have a value.

The part after the `=` sign is an expression, though.

> ```
> val m = Map(1 -> 2, 2 -> 4)
> ```

In Scala, `foo(bar)` can mean one of two things:

- calling the method `foo` implicitly on `this` passing `bar` as an argument.
- [calling the method `apply` on the object obtained by evaluating the expression `foo` passing `bar` as an argument](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/06-expressions.html#function-applications).

So, `foo(bar)` is equivalent to either

```
this.foo(bar)
```

or

```
foo.apply(bar)
```

depending on which is available in the current scope.

In this particular case, there is no method named `Map` defined in the current scope, it corresponds to the second meaning:

```
Map.apply(1 -> 2, 2 -> 4)
```

Where does `Map` come from? This is actually [`scala.Predef.Map`](https://scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Predef$.html#Map:scala.collection.immutable.Map.type), which is defined in `scala.Predef` which is an `object` that gets automatically `import`ed into every Scala program. Note: don't confuse the *`val`ue* [`scala.Predef.Map`](https://scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Predef$.html#Map:scala.collection.immutable.Map.type) which is an alias for the *`object`* [`scala.collection.immutable.Map`](https://scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/Map$.html) with the *`type` alias* [`scala.Predef.Map[A, B]`](https://scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Predef$.html#Map%5BA,+B%5D=scala.collection.immutable.Map%5BA,B%5D) which is an alias for the *`trait`* [`scala.collection.immutable.Map`](https://scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/Map.html).

Values and types live in completely separate universes in Scala (like in most other programming languages), therefore it is perfectly possible for them to have the same name, since they can never appear in the same context and thus there can never be an ambiguity.

So, let's look at [the documentation for `Map.apply`](https://scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/Map$.html#apply%5BA,B%5D(elems:(A,B)*):CC%5BA,B%5D) to tell us what it does:

> ## `def apply[A, B](elems: (A, B)*): Map[A, B]`
>
> A collection of type `Map` that contains given key/value bindings.

So, `Map.apply` returns a `Map` that contains the key/value pairs that we pass as arguments. But wait, `apply` takes [repeated parameters](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/04-basic-declarations-and-definitions.html#repeated-parameters) of type `(A, B)` (which is [syntactic sugar](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/03-types.html#tuple-types) for [`Tuple2[A, B]`](https://scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Tuple2.html)), but we are not passing a `Tuple2`, i.e. we are not passing `(1, 2), (2, 4)` as arguments but rather `1 -> 2, 2 -> 4`, so what is this?

Remember that in Scala, a much wider range of identifiers is allowed than in many other languages. Also remember that methods can be called without a period, and that if a method is called without a period and you are passing only a single argument, you can leave out the parentheses. So,

```
1 -> 2
```

is the same as

```
1 ->(2)
```

is the same as

```
1.->(2)
```

All this does is call the method `->` (which is just a boring standard Scala method name, nothing at all special about it) on `1` passing `2` as the argument. Now, it turns out that [`Int` doesn't have a `->` method](https://scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Int.html), but there is an [`implicit class ArrayAssoc`](https://scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Predef$.html#ArrowAssoc%5BA%5DextendsAnyVal) which adds the methods [`->`](https://scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Predef$$ArrowAssoc.html#-%3E%5BB%5D(y:B):(A,B)) as well as [`→`](https://scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Predef$$ArrowAssoc.html#%E2%86%92%5BB%5D(y:B):(A,B)) to `Any` type and … tadaaa … returns a `Tuple2[A, B]`.

Alright. Putting it all together:

```
1 -> 2
```

is the same as

```
1 ->(2)
```

is the same as

```
1.->(2)
```

which is actually calling `ArrowAssoc.->` which returns

```
(1, 2)
```

which is syntactic sugar for

```
new Tuple2(1, 2)
```

(and the same for `2 -> 4`) which we are passing to

```
Map(new Tuple2(1, 2), new Tuple2(3, 4))
```

which is actually

```
scala.Predef.Map(new Tuple2(1, 2), new Tuple2(3, 4))
```

which is assigned to

```
scala.collection.immutable.Map(new Tuple2(1, 2), new Tuple2(3, 4))
```

which is actually

```
scala.collection.immutable.Map.apply(new Tuple2(1, 2), new Tuple2(3, 4))
```

which returns a new instance of some unspecified implementation class of the `trait scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int, Int]` with the key `1` associated with the value `2` and the key `2` associated with the value `4`.

> This is the return value:
>
> ```
> scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int, Int] = Map(1 -> 2, 2 -> 4)
> ```

To be pedantic: this is the *string representation* of the return value, obtained by calling `toString()` on it. `Map` overrides `toString()` and represents its contents using the same `->` that could be used to construct it.

Answer (score 1):

`a -> b` is syntactic sugar for creating a tuple `(a, b)`.

The scala `Map` constructor takes an arbitrary number of tuples `(a, b)` as arguments and creates a [mapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array) from the first element of each tuple to the second. In your case, since you are populating it with integers, it generates a `Map[Int, Int]`: A mapping from integers to integers.

You can now use your map e.g. as follows:

```
m(1)  // Has value 2
m(2)  // Has value 4
```

Comment: m(3) will throw NoSuchElementException. Best practice is to use m.get(3) which will return an Option.

Comment: @Mukeshprajapati Well that rather depends on the application, does it not? In situations where one can be sure a key is present regardless of input, would I not rather use direct access as above, for clarity? In situations where I do not have this guarantee, however, I would indeed prefer the .get() or .getOrElse() methods.

Comment: yeah...that's right and that's why i mentioned "Best practice".